# Simple use of Mockito AnyMap is not working

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest

Why does anyMap not work here in this simple case? I get func1 cannot be matched with this signature?

```
case class foo() {def func1 (m: Map[Int, Int]) = m.size }

case class SomeTest extends SomeSpec MockitoSugar with MustMatchers {
   it("checks size ") { fixture =>
      val spyfoo = spy(foo())
      doReturn(5).when(spyfoo).func1(anyMap())}
```

I get the func1 cannot be recognized with this signature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer; I don't use ScalaTest, but as it appears that Mockito functionality is provided as-is, you should be able to use anything from the [`Matchers`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Matchers.html) class.

**However** the provided `anyMap()` and `anyMapOf[K,V]` functions are matchers for `java.util.Map` and so won't match your `func1` method signature which (unless you've explicitly brought in `java.util.Map`) is expecting a `scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int]`.

The easiest way around this would seem to be using the generic [`any[T]`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Matchers.html#any(java.lang.Class)) matcher, which is very loose, but does what you need.

There are more problems though - why are you `spy()`ing on an object you own? And why are you trying to *return* a `Map` in your mocked behaviour for `func1` when it *takes* a `Map` and returns an `Int`?

This compiles and works for me:

```
import org.mockito.{Matchers, Mockito}

val mockFoo = Mockito.mock(classOf[Foo])

Mockito.when(mockFoo.func1(Matchers.any(classOf[Map[Int, Int]]))).thenReturn(1)

...
```

Comment: spying on object; Debatable, but I think partial mocks have their use cases. In my case: I am calling an external [no control over types], and I wanted ti test if i am passing the right parameters to that.  As for returning a Map => left over typo, corrected

Comment: Also i believe that for spy, Mockito suggests doReturn(n).when(mockfoo).func1(Matchers.any(classOf[Map[Int, Int]])) instead of "when..doReturn"